# Set up Run Configuration for embedded system

Tags: c, eclipse, embedded, stm32, run-configuration

I have a STM32F10 RB Nucleo blinking its LED using a project written and built in Atollic TrueSTUDIO® for ARM®, Built on Eclipse (Version: 5.4.0).

The debug configuration works fine, all I'm trying to do is set up a run configuration and I'm getting a slew of errors. 
Can anyone provide a walk-through? My understanding is to go to `Run >> Run Configurations` and do something...

I've read I should just copy the debug configuration, so I copied the contents of fields `C/C++ Application` as well as `Project` in the `Main` tab. Should I do anything else to any other tab, such as `Source` or `Common`?

---

Some errors:

> The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches.
>
> Error starting process.
>
> Cannot run program "C:\Users\Karl\Atollic\TrueSTUDIO\chipset\chipset
>   2\NewRelease\chipset 2.elf": Launching failed
>
> Cannot run program "C:\Users\Karl\Atollic\TrueSTUDIO\chipset\chipset
>   2\NewRelease\chipset 2.elf": Launching failed
>
> Cannot run program  Launching failed

Answer (score 0):

in eclipse:  with the project open:

click menu item `file`

in the drop down menu click `properties` (may have to modify some file source first, like inserting a space).

In Properties window.  to right of the prompt: `Configuration:` (it probably says `Debug [Active]`

to far right is button: `Manage Configurations`

click `Manage Configurations`  a Manage Configurations window opens

If the column titled: `Configuration` contains a name: `Release`, then click that name.  else click`new` and follow the prompts.

.. later..
click menu item: `Project`

in the drop down menu click: `Rebuild All`

Absolutely nothing else needs to be done,

Comment: I've been trying that but that's what gives me the error "The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches." when I try to run it...

Comment: you do have to setup EACH configuration separately.  In general, there are few differences between the debug and release configurations, just a parameter or two for the compile and build steps.

Comment: @user3629249 I'm having this same problem, and even with adding a "Release" configuration and rebuilding everything (the project builds), the same error comes up when I try to run it. Do you know of any other fixes?